# Why can't RegularGridInterpolator not return several values (for a function that outputs in $R^d$)

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

MRE (with working output and output that doesn't work although I would like it to work as it would be the intuitional thing to do):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator, griddata

def f(x1, x2, x3):
    return x1 + 2*x2 + 3*x3, x1**2, x2

# Define the input points
xi = [np.linspace(0, 1, 5), np.linspace(0, 1, 5), np.linspace(0, 1, 5)]

# Mesh grid
x1, x2, x3 = np.meshgrid(*xi, indexing='ij')

# Outputs
y = f(x1, x2, x3)
assert (y[0][1][1][3] == (0.25 + 2*0.25 + 3*0.75))
assert (y[1][1][1][3] == (0.25**2))
assert (y[2][1][1][3] == 0.25)

#### THIS WORKS BUT I CAN ONLY GET THE nth (with n integer in [1, d]) VALUE RETURNED BY f
# Interpolate at point 0.3, 0.3, 0.4
interp = RegularGridInterpolator(xi, y[0])
print(interp([0.3, 0.3, 0.4]))  # outputs 2.1 as expected


#### THIS DOESN'T WORK (I WOULD'VE EXPECTED A LIST OF TUPLES FOR EXAMPLE)
# Interpolate at point 0.3, 0.3, 0.4
interp = RegularGridInterpolator(xi, y)
print(interp([0.3, 0.3, 0.4]))  # doesn't output array([2.1, 0.1, 0.3])
```

What is intriguing is that griddata does support functions that output values in `R^d`

```py
# Same with griddata
grid_for_griddata = np.array([x1.flatten(), x2.flatten(), x3.flatten()]).T
assert (grid_for_griddata.shape == (125, 3))
y_for_griddata = np.array([y[0].flatten(), y[1].flatten(), y[2].flatten()]).T
assert (y_for_griddata.shape == (125, 3))
griddata(grid_for_griddata, y_for_griddata, [0.3, 0.3, 0.4], method='linear')[0]  # outputs array([2.1, 0.1, 0.3]) as expected
```

Am I using `RegularGridInterpolator` the wrong way?

I know someone might say "just use `griddata`", but because my data is in a rectilinear grid, I should use `RegularGridInterpolator` so that it's faster, right?

Proof that it's faster:
[image]

Comment: I haven't used these functions much, but indeed it does look like `RegularGridInterpolator` only works with one value per grid point.  As for why - generally we can't answer that - unless we happen to be a scipy developer, or have otherwise dug into the guts of this function.

Comment: `interp = RegularGridInterpolator(xi, y)` produces a `ValueError`.  You can't even get to the `interp(...)` step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I define a `y` with the 3 as last dimension:

```
In [196]: yarr = np.stack(y,axis=3); yarr.shape
Out[196]: (5, 5, 5, 3)
```

Setup works (no complaints about 3 not matching 5):

```
In [197]: interp = RegularGridInterpolator(xi, yarr)
```

And the interpolation:

```
In [198]: interp([.3,.3,.4])
Out[198]: array([[2.1, 0.1, 0.3]])
```

and for multiple points:

```
In [202]: interp([[.3,.3,.4],[.31,.31,.41],[.5,.4,.4]])
Out[202]: 
array([[2.1   , 0.1   , 0.3   ],
       [2.16  , 0.1075, 0.31  ],
       [2.5   , 0.25  , 0.4   ]])
```

While the above was just a guess that works, I see that the docs can be interpreted this way:

```
values: array_like, shape (m1, …, mn, …)
```

The `...` at the end suggest that the array may have 0 or more trailing dimensions (beyond the `n` that match the points dimensions).  But this flexibility may apply more to the `linear` and `nearest` methods.  Others seem to have problems.

This is clearer on the doc page for its `__call__`:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.__call__

```
Returns
    values_x : ndarray, shape xi.shape[:-1] + values.shape[ndim:]
```

`interpn` also documents this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand `shape xi.shape[:-1] + values.shape[ndim:]`, `xi.shape` in `interp([[.3,.3,.4],[.31,.31,.41],[.5,.4,.4]])` is `(1, )` right? (because we drop the `3`) and `values.shape[ndim:]` is `(3, )`, so we get `(1, 3)` but we clearly see that we get `(1, 3, 3)`

Comment: Where's that (1,3) from?  Your `xi` is (3,3).  For [198], the result is (1,3).

Comment: My bad ... everything's clear (we also get `3, 3` not `1, 3, 3` sorry). I'm just not used to those notations, what a headache